# Stack Overflow and Stack Overflow Meta logo is offset in IE10

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, logo, menu-bar

I know IE will be gone soon, but not soon enough.

There are still some who will choose not to update to IE11.

Here are some screenshots:

Stack Overflow:

[image: Stackoverflow img]

Stack Overflow Meta

[image: StackoverflowMeta Img]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343937/new-navigation-bar-layout-is-completely-broken-in-ie-10/343979#343979